# how to print the date in french as follows: Fri 29 Mar 2019 22:53:00

Tags: robotframework

I want to print the date as follows `(Ven 29 Mar 2019 22:53:00)` but the result is the following `(ven. 29 Mar 2019 22:53)`
the v is in tiny and there is a point after the ven

I use the following code to get the date in french

```
Evaluate    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'French')    locale
```

this is the syntax I use for formatting:

```
${startDate} =    Get Current Date 


result_format =a% d% b% Y% %H:%M
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string in two - the first word, and the rest, by using [Split String](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Split%20String) with `max_split` equal to 1:

```
${splited}=    Split String     ${your date string}    max_split=1
```

[Remove](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Remove%20String) the dot character, and capitalize the first letter by using [python's `title()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title)  method on the first member of the split:

```
${first}=    Remove String    ${splited[0]}    .
${first}=    Evaluate    "${first}".title()
```

And now combine the title-cased word with the remaining part of the split:

```
${result}=    Catenate    ${first}    ${splited[1]}
# alternatively Set Variable will also do for a simple case like this
${result}=    Set Variable    ${first} ${splited[1]}
```

By the way, I see you also want seconds in your date string, the formatting pattern should be like this in this case:

```
%a d% b% Y% %H:%M:%S
```